# Eloquent model update returns true but db change not reflecting

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-models

I have a model called CustomerInfo and i am trying to update it. update returns true but the changes are not reflecting on my db.

```
$customerInfo = CustomerInfo::where('machine_name',$username)->firstOrFail();
$result = $customerInfo->update($data);
```

**$data** varaible is a array having key value pair.
Also tried the following

```
$customerInfo = CustomerInfo::where('machine_name',$username)->update($data);
```

Comment: Can you let us know if `$customerInfo = CustomerInfo::where('machine_name',$username)->get()->dd();` contains any results?

Comment: Have you added fillable property in your `CustomerInfo` Model?
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: If you are using Eloquent manual transactions please be sure to use DB::commit(); at the end

Comment: Thank Luciano.
Sorry i forgot to commit my db transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my questions.
Thanks Luciano.
i started eloquent manual db transaction and forgot to commit it at the end

```
DB::beginTransaction();//did this
$customerInfo = CustomerInfo::where('machine_name',$username)->firstOrFail();
$result = $customerInfo->update($data);
DB::Commit() //forgot to implement this part.
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure $data variable that you want update record by its values, not be same with that record.
in this case, you don't have sql error but return of update will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $customerInfo->update($data);
```

`$result` variable will return only the boolean value. Try to return `$customerInfo` i.e.

```
return response()->json($customerInfo);
```

This will help you to find the actual problem and make sure the `CustmerInfo` model contains fillable properties and the `$data` variable contains all the information.

Try to use `dd()` like below to identify the issue:

```
dd($variable);
```